# Why I delete a Key-Value from plist ,It shows success,but later it re-appears?

Tags: swift, tableview, plist, tablecell

I was programming a Tableviewcontroller,and the cell's data is from a file with the type of `plist`.The plist file is a Dictionary,I read the plist file like this:

```
if let path=Bundle.main.path(forResource:"XXX", ofType: "plist"){
    CellDic=NSDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary;
}
```

the I want to proform a function to delete a Key-Value from the tableview and the plist file ,so I did like this:

```
var key=(CellDic as NSDictionary).allKeys[indexPath.row];
CellDic.removeValue(forKey:(key as! String));
if let path=Bundle.main.path(forResource:"XXX", ofType: "plist"){
    (CellDic as NSDictionary).write(toFile: path, atomically: false);        
}
tableView.reloadData();
```

It appears the cell is deleted,But When the tableview shows again,the cell I just deleted was appeared!!Addition，I did not quit the program,nor stop Debuging

Comment: Don't use `;` as line terminators in Swift, and don't start func or variable names with uppercase letters

Comment: OK，But I also want to ask how to solve the problem?